# Merge large images on disk

Tags: python, image, mapreduce, computer-vision

### The main problem:

I have a map step where I render a large amount of sectors of an image in parallel:

```
1 2
3 4

worker a -> 1
worker b -> 2
...

merge 1,2,3,4 to make final image
```

### If it can fit in memory

With images that are relatively small and can fit in RAM, one can simply use PIL's functionality:

```
def merge_images(image_files, x, y):
    images = map(Image.open, image_files)
    width, height = images[0].size    
    new_im = Image.new('RGB', (width * x, height * y))
    for n, im in enumerate(images):
        new_im.paste(im, ((n%x) * width, (n//y) * height))
    return new_im
```

Unfortunately, I am going to have *many, many large sectors*. I want to merge the pictures finally into a single image of about 40,000 x 60,000 pixels, which I estimate to be around 20 GB's. (Or maybe even more)

So obviously, we can't approach this problem on RAM. I know there are alternatives like `memmap`'ing arrays and writing to slices, which I will try. However, **I am looking for as-out-of-the-box-as-possible solutions**.

Does anyone know of any easier alternatives? **Even though all the approaches I've tried so far is in python, it doesn't need to be in python**.

Comment: Write the image to a tiled TIFF file. You can create the file writing individual tiles to it.

Comment: @CrisLuengo could you elaborate or provide some pointers on documentation or code snippets? I’ll accept your answer after I read up on it and implement it

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[pyvips](https://pypi.org/project/pyvips/) can do exactly what you want very quickly and efficiently. For example:

```
import sys
import pyvips

images = [pyvips.Image.new_from_file(filename, access="sequential")
          for filename in sys.argv[2:]]
final = pyvips.Image.arrayjoin(images, across=10)
final.write_to_file(sys.argv[1])
```

The `access="sequential"` option tells pyvips that you want to stream the image. It will only load pixels on demand as it generates output, so you can merge enormous images using only a little memory. The [`arrayjoin`](https://libvips.github.io/libvips/API/current/libvips-conversion.html#vips-arrayjoin) operator joins an array of images into a grid `across` tiles across. It has quite a few layout options: you can specify borders, overlaps, background, centring behaviour and so on.

I can run it like this:

```
$ for i in {1..100}; do cp ~/pics/k2.jpg $i.jpg; done
$ time ../arrayjoin.py x.tif *.jpg 

real    0m2.498s
user    0m3.579s
sys 0m1.054s
$ vipsheader x.tif
x.tif: 14500x20480 uchar, 3 bands, srgb, tiffload
```

So it joined 100 JPG images to make a 14,000 x 20,000 pixel mosaic in about 2.5s on this laptop, and from watching `top`, needed about 300mb of memory. I've used it to join over 30,000 images into a single file, and it would go higher. I've made images of over 300,000 by 300,000 pixels.

The pyvips equivalent of PIL's `paste` is [`insert`](https://libvips.github.io/libvips/API/current/libvips-conversion.html#vips-insert). You could use that too, though it won't work so well for very large numbers of images.

There's also a command-line interface, so you could just enter:

```
vips arrayjoin "${echo *.jpg}" x.tif --across 10
```

To join up a large set of JPG images.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using the TIFF file format. Most TIFF files are striped (one or more scan lines are stored as a block on file), but it is possible to write tiled TIFF files (where the image is divided into tiles, and each is stored as an independent block on file).

[LibTIFF](http://www.simplesystems.org/libtiff/) is the canonical way of reading and writing TIFF files. It has an easy way of creating a new TIFF file, and add tiles one at the time. Thus, your program can create the TIFF file, obtain one sector, write it as (one or more) tiles to the TIFF file, obtain the next sector, etc. You would have to choose your tile size to evenly divide one sector.

There is a Python binding to LibTIFF called, what else, [PyLibTIFF](https://github.com/pearu/pylibtiff). It should allow you to follow the above model from within Python. That same repository has pure Python module to read and write TIFF files, I don't know if that is able to write TIFF files in tiles, or if it allows to write them in chunks. There are many other Python modules for reading and writing TIFF files, but most will write one matrix as a TIFF file, rather than allow you to write a file one tile at a time.