# BioImage slicing and stitching in Python without losing information

Tags: python, image-processing, image-stitching, image-slicer

I am a python newbie learning by doing and working as a medical researcher on large images with a lot of biological data about cell marker expressions. I have a short processing code that does a channel separation and turning the channels as fluorescene (pseudo) and/or grayscale.
When trying to process a larger image we dont have enough memory so the way to go is to slice the image in processable tiles, perform the channel formatting and then stich the image back together.
I really have 0 idea how the stitching and slicing work incorporated with this channel separation.

I used these snippets from scikit_image

```
import numpy as np`
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

from skimage import data
from skimage.color import rgb2hed, hed2rgb

**# Example IHC image(512, 512, 3) uint8**
ihc_rgb = data.immunohistochemistry()

**# Separate the stains from the IHC image**
ihc_hed = rgb2hed(ihc_rgb)

**# Create an RGB image for each of the stains**
null = np.zeros_like(ihc_hed[:, :, 0])
ihc_h = hed2rgb(np.stack((ihc_hed[:, :, 0], null, null), axis=-1))
ihc_e = hed2rgb(np.stack((null, ihc_hed[:, :, 1], null), axis=-1))
ihc_d = hed2rgb(np.stack((null, null, ihc_hed[:, :, 2]), axis=-1))

**# Display**
fig, axes = plt.subplots(2, 2, figsize=(7, 6), sharex=True, sharey=True)
ax = axes.ravel()

ax[0].imshow(ihc_rgb)
ax[0].set_title("Original image")

ax[1].imshow(ihc_h)
ax[1].set_title("Hematoxylin")

ax[2].imshow(ihc_e)
ax[2].set_title("Eosin")  # Note that there is no Eosin stain in this image

ax[3].imshow(ihc_d)
ax[3].set_title("DAB")

for a in ax.ravel():
    a.axis('off')

fig.tight_layout()

from skimage.exposure import rescale_intensity

**# Rescale hematoxylin and DAB channels and give them a fluorescence look**
h = rescale_intensity(ihc_hed[:, :, 0], out_range=(0, 1),
                      in_range=(0, np.percentile(ihc_hed[:, :, 0], 99)))
d = rescale_intensity(ihc_hed[:, :, 2], out_range=(0, 1),
                      in_range=(0, np.percentile(ihc_hed[:, :, 2], 99)))
**
**# Cast the two channels into an RGB image, as the blue and green channels
**# respectively******
zdh = np.dstack((null, d, h))

fig = plt.figure()
axis = plt.subplot(1, 1, 1, sharex=ax[0], sharey=ax[0])
axis.imshow(zdh)
axis.set_title('Stain-separated image (rescaled)')
axis.axis('off')
plt.show()
```

I want to translate this to a large image.

Comment: how many channels does your image have (array shape?)  ? how big is it (image size) ? whay kind of image is 8bit , 16bit 32bit   , please provide some code to generate an input image , see examples here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60604762/trying-to-generate-random-picture-with-pil-but-get-strange-result , I know cant create a image that is that big , but just one we could play to try to use your code with we need an https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: ok got it your example image is skimage.data.immunohistochemistry() (512, 512, 3) uint8 ndarray min 0 max 255

Comment: I have IHC image like you correctly identified. I am terribly sorry for not understanding all here....Still learning.
The image is around 66000x70000 pixels ~ 600mb large.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5953373/how-to-split-image-into-multiple-pieces-in-python

Comment: what format is your image file ?? Is it .tiff , 8 or 16 bit ? how do you read it in chuncks ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70458133/how-to-read-a-large-image-by-lines-with-python see second answer You can use pyvips to read out parts of a tiled TIFF. For example:

Comment: its a .tiff image and I wasnt able to read because of memroy problems.
I will look in the answers provided

Comment: I tried only reading it as a whole slide. Then wanted to make it in chunks and process it with the script further and after all tiles are processed to be able to stitch the iamge back together all in one code in Python. I do beginn to realize that maybe another approach is needed.

Answer (score 0):

given the advice in [how to read a large image by lines with python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70458133/how-to-read-a-large-image-by-lines-with-python) :

> I would suggest you tile your rather large TIFF outside of Python before you start. Drawing heavily on John's (@jcupitt) answer here, you can do that with vips.

I tried to reproduce your problem. I am a newbie to image-processing and Python too, so bear with me , my code below, I choose the [pyvips](https://pypi.org/project/pyvips/) that   wraps the libvips image processing library because I found a lot of help about it here on SO:

```
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np

import pyvips

# CREATE 10000*10000*3 black image 

# array = np.zeros((10000, 10000, 3), dtype=np.uint8)
# image = pyvips.Image.new_from_array(array)
# image.write_to_file("huge.tif")


# fields = image.get_fields()
 
# print(fields) 


# img = image.numpy()

# print('img : ', img.size, img.shape , img.ndim)


# load the 10000*10000*3 black image , without loaing it !!! this should be where we can load your huge tif
img_loaded = pyvips.Image.new_from_file('huge.tif', access='sequential')


print(img_loaded, img_loaded.width , img_loaded.height, img_loaded.bands)


hg = 0

for i in range(img_loaded.height//1000):
    
    # https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48281086/extracting-a-region-of-interest-from-an-image-file-without-reading-the-entire-im
    
    
    # uses pyvips pointer to loaded image to load part of it 
    # get the numpy array corresponding to it
    # change same of the images
    # saves them one by one 
    #IMPORTANT script works because we know 10000/10 is round no pixel leftover
    
    a = img_loaded.crop(0, i*1000, img_loaded.width, 1000)
    
    
    arr = a.numpy()
    
    print(arr.size , arr.shape , arr.ndim)
    
    # aa = Image.fromarray(arr)
    # aa.show()
    
    if i%2 == 0 :
        
        arr[:,:,0] = 0
        arr[:,:,1] = 255
        arr[:,:,2] = 0
        
        print('i%2 : ', i % 2)
        
        aa = Image.fromarray(arr)
        aa.show()
        
        aa.save('bit_'+str(i)+'.tif')
        
    
    elif i == 3 or i == 9 :
        
        arr[:,:,0] = 255
        arr[:,:,1] = 0
        arr[:,:,2] = 0
        
    
        aa = Image.fromarray(arr)
        aa.show()
        
        aa.save('bit_'+str(i)+'.tif')
       
    else:
        
        print('i%2 : ', i % 2)
        
        aa = Image.fromarray(arr)
        aa.show()
        
        aa.save('bit_'+str(i)+'.tif')
        
 
        
# https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50297176/merge-large-images-on-disk

# load each of the images from above without loading them , and join again

images = [pyvips.Image.new_from_file(filename, access="sequential")
          for filename in ['bit_'+str(i)+'.tif' for i in range(img_loaded.height//1000)   ] ]

final = pyvips.Image.arrayjoin(images, across = 1)

final.write_to_file('result.tiff')
```

the first lines of my script:

```
# CREATE 10000*10000*3 black image 

# array = np.zeros((10000, 10000, 3), dtype=np.uint8)
# image = pyvips.Image.new_from_array(array)
# image.write_to_file("huge.tif")
```

create my supposed `huge.tif` file , is not that big but ......

[image]

`exiftool huge.tif` gives the details :

```
Image Width                     : 10000
Image Height                    : 10000
Bits Per Sample                 : 8 8 8
```

the second part of the code load , without loading in memory , such file

and operates same changes on part of it extracted and converted to `numpy` arrays that are finally saved as smaller `.tif` files via `Pillow`library.

Then the resulting pics are not loaded again via `pyvips` and merged to a not in memory file written to disk, I don't know if I made same mistake the resulting `result.tiff` files has same dimensions of input one :

[image]

I am new to big tiff files , this should provide a way to handle them, see inside my code some link to relevant SO questions whose solutions I used to create this snippet